# Reported 13 instances of plagiarism by user - was I being a bully, a busybody, or helpful?

Tags: discussion, moderation, plagiarism, attribution

**Background**

I found an answer which a user had posted was copied **verbatim** from elsewhere without attribution. I flagged it for moderator attention, and thought nothing more of it.

After some thought, I was wondering if it was a one-off incident and ended up finding a pattern of the same user copying answers from elsewhere and reposting as their own answer without attribution or other acknowledgement that it wasn't their own work.

**My actions**

Finding plagiarised answers was very easy. Answers were copied without any attempt to change formatting, correct typos (like "`sucsseful`" [sic]), change references to members which didn't relate to the question (e.g. `drop_down_SelectedIndexChanged` when there was no dropdown anywhere), or language incongruous to the users' own (e.g. "`may wanna leave it empty`").

Each time I found this behaviour I left a courteous comment on the answer telling the user what they were doing wrong, linking to the plagiarised original, and imploring them to attribute the original author.

In the end, I flagged **thirteen** posts of that nature. Some had been accepted as answers, some upvoted as good answers, others correctly downvoted as their relation to the question was tenuous (e.g. a VB.net answer to a C# question).

I did not explicitly downvote any of the answers in the event that my findings were incorrect.

**Status**

As I write this, of the thirteen flags I raised, five answers have been deleted (I assume by a moderator - my flags been marked 'helpful'), one has been deleted by the user.

**Status - one day later**

I've just checked my flags and have seen that all thirteen posts have been marked helpful, and the posts removed (at least *one* I know the user removed themselves).

**Question**

Was I wrong to do this? I worry that my actions may be seen as bullying since I ended up going through the user's answers and searching for plagiarism. The user had been "last seen" regularly while I did this so they will have had lots of notifications from me.

---

**Some related questions**

- "[*What to do when plagiarism is discovered*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/284827)" (suggested by @hichris123)
- "[*Should I flag plagiarism for moderator attention?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122056/284827)"
- "[*Moderator declined a plagiarism flag*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156080/284827)" (marked a duplicate of "*Should I flag plagiarism for moderator attention?*")

Comment: You are doing a very good thing keeping trash off of this site, or reducing trashy behavior. Thank you.

Comment: Really rather best to leave this to the moderators to deal with.  That way you won't expose yourself to reprisals, that can get ugly in a hurry.  Flagging gets the job done.

Comment: See also: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels — my actions were based on how I think I'd feel if somebody decided to copy one of my own answers as their own. Also, being [licenced under creative commons](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/now-licensed-under-creative-commons/), I'm not sure if there are any legal ramifications to plagiarised content from outside the stack exchange being tolerated. I use StackOverflow a lot for my work, and it's my instinct to protect it for my own selfish reasons.

Comment: @HansPassant — I tried to leave the feedback to the user in as courteous a manner as possible in case they were unaware that they were doing wrong, but I can see where things could go sour quickly. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I think questions on which answers copied from somewhere are accepted can be flagged as duplicate too. That's what I usually do while I flag the answer too

Comment: @HansPassant — I see what you mean. A couple of my answers (this question is my first anywhere on the StackExchange) were just voted down. The user in question now no longer had sufficient reputation to vote down - I'm not sure if privileges remain if they've *once* been available or not. Could've been anyone, I guess. Ho hum.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

That's helpful.  Copying content without attribution at all is plagiarism, and is indeed an offense that should be dealt with.

Thanks for doing that, and hopefully you continue the trend if you see any more posts doing this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I *think* I'm reasonably fastidious about raising good flags (of the 320 flags I've raised since I started being active in February, 253 have been marked as useful, and 8 were declined or disputed), so I will continue my actions.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Just out of curiousity, what were the other 59 flags?

Comment: @PeterOlson From what I've seen around here about the flag backlog, they're probably just still unactioned.

Comment: @WaiHaLee - I handled a bunch of these, and I want to particularly thank you for providing links to the posts or pages they were copied from. That saves us a lot of time, because we don't have to search for the source and can directly compare the linked content to what they posted. Finding original sources is the most time-consuming aspect of dealing with users flagged for plagiarizing material.

Comment: @PeterOlson — the current values are: 324 flags, of which 261 were marked useful, 9 declined or disputed, 27 waiting for review, and 54 (*= 324-261-9*) must have aged away. Of the 27, about 15 are less than a week old (I'm not sure what the turnaround time is). The flags waiting for review or aged away seem to mainly comprise { off topic, primarily opinion based, too broad }. My flags for { spam, not an answer, very low quality, (foreign-language answer) } have a very high accept rate, though I don't have the tools to tell you (I've not looked on [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/) yet).

Comment: @BradLarson — finding the plagiarised answers was **very** easy. Answers were copied without any attempt to change formatting, correct typos (like "sucsseful" [sic]), or change specific member names which didn't come from the question (e.g. `drop_down_SelectedIndexChanged` when there was no dropdown anywhere). As I said in my question, the StackOverflow community had largely downvoted completely irrelevant answers (the system works!). Typos or language incongruous to the users' own (e.g. "*this is displayed once logged in. may wanna leave it empty*") made searching very easy.

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee: Which is great - keep doing that. Providing the source links in your flags takes away that unnecessary step from our process entirely, regardless of how easy it is. The less that a moderator has to do that a regular user can do *while they are flagging*, the better. Allow me to extend my thanks to you for your help as well.

Comment: @BoltClock and BradLarson — thanks for the words of encouragement. I'd like to take the opportunity to thank you and the moderators as a whole for your work to keep the site clean, especially since the position (while attained through [election](http://stackoverflow.com/election)) doesn't come with any particular reward other than the diamond and the extra moderation power.

Comment: I know that "ignorance of the law is not excuse" [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignorantia_juris_non_excusat) and I appreciate @waiHaLee approach of gentle admonition. It gives the newbie (like myself) the opportunity to correct the mistake, which is the path to wisdom.