# Are other reviewers opting to use no comment to avoid confrontation and is this a problem?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

When reviewing the Low Quality Review Queue, I've found myself opting for no comment needed when there is no previous review comment as I don't want to have my name beside the review comment.

[image: The auto-comments dialog]

I sometimes find that the ensuing pings and arguments with the poster can become tiring. The review comment can result in a plethora of questions from the OP.

Sometimes people will assume the reviewer has downvoted the post, and do not understand that rarely would the reviewed be the person who has flagged the post as low quality.

For example, [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10775143); there was something about the OPs attitude that made me want to remain completely anonymous to them as a reviewer.

I want to know:

1. Do other reviewers feel this way about commenting?
2. Is it a problem not to use a comment?
3. Would it be better to skip, even though I am sure of my vote, but am not keen to leave a comment?

Comment: for sure commenting on low stuff from low rep users can lead into a LOT of arguing and problems. I don't know for other reviewers, but I actually rarely took the "no comment" route. If I'm not willing to "take the frak" of whoever responds to my comment, then I will skip that review instead of doing it half-assed... but that's just me

Comment: @Patrice I guess that's a good point and kinda what I'm asking, should I skip it. It really depends on my energy levels, sometimes I'm just not up for it. And I do a lot of reviewing in the close review queue and am active there and will discuss things with OP.

Comment: Honestly, when I'm not "up for it", I will skip these, instead of skipping a comment. But again, that's just me

Comment: @Patrice that's why I asked this, I edited question, feel free to post an answer, I'm not sure if there is a definitive right or wrong.

Comment: If/when somebody does recommend deletion with a comment, your name is there anyway. The only *sure* way to not have your name associated with the review action is to skip it.

Comment: @WaiHaLee yes, but the Op of the post generally doesn't see that. I don't mind people seeing my review history, it's the comments under the post I am reluctant with at times

Comment: Fair enough. I say this as somebody who's only done ~3000 reviews in that queue (not sure how many you have, but presumably more), but I've found that the ["From Review" automatically-added link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309704/1364007) has made it so that fewer people @mention me to argue - I'm not sure if it's made clear to them when they follow the link how their answer has ended up in the queue, or if they just have to Google it/look on meta/chat (if they know about meta/chat) to find out themselves.

Comment: yeh I think the REveiw link is good @WaiHaLee

Comment: I also notice the reviewer before me left no comment, wonder why.

Comment: In the [case](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10775143) you linked to in your answer, I didn't leave a comment because there was already [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418208/install-google-chrome-or-mozilla-firefox-in-windows-surface/34601856#comment56951235_34601856) which was more specific than any of the default reasons. I suspect that's why the other reviewers didn't leave a comment too.

Comment: @WaiHaLee yeh I figured that, I mean the person who reviewed before me.

Comment: I treat the canned comments as the Jobs button in the navigation. It's there for when I need it. I hardly ever need it.

Comment: @Normal what do you mean by jobs button? :)

Comment: I don't leave comments when the appropriate comment has already been left, because duplicate comments are silly and probably aggravating to the post's author. I think the behavior's been changed recently so that picking a comment that's already present upvotes that comment instead of leaving a new one, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly in all cases.

Comment: The confrontation part of the problem was the reasoning behind adding "From Review" to every comment posted from the queues. However, I do not think that the no comment button is a problem, in my experience there is usually someone (who hasn't gotten fed up with the flame wars that the comments usually start) that will post a comment down the line if they haven't already.

Comment: @TinyGiant thank you for your kind understanding, or is this just cos you're too scared to disagree :p

Comment: I'm not scared of anything, except for the nightmares about a giant wall of crap with no end.

Comment: @TinyGiant a tiny giant wall...?

Comment: I don't know if something can be tiny, *and* have no end. I'll have to ponder that.

Comment: @TinyGiant ponder it....?

Comment: Well, most posts legitimately in the queue already have a good enough comment. And most of the tiny rest don't give me any hope that a comment will help anything. Which just leaves a handful...

Comment: so really the consensus is, it doesn't matter and it's probably better to keep reviewing, mind you the low qual queue is not out of control..

Comment: Problem with these really is that some people are not content with disagreeing with your comment. They will actively flame you, insult you, revenge-downvote you (thats reversed mostly).

Comment: @Magisch - has this happened to you? I tend to leave comments a fair proportion of the times (I think) if there isn't one - a few times I have [called somebody out on plagiarism](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289393/1364007) and rarely get users reply, and have never (so far) had revenge downvotes, etc.

Comment: @WaiHaLee didn't get revenge downvotes so far, but a couple people insulted me in reply comments.

Comment: Wait, people still drop comments when reviewing trash?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No. 3) No.

Comment: You're lucky to have the option to remain anonymous. Dupehammering puts a big John Hancock on the closure, which invites an endless stream of "my/OP's question isn't a duplicate because it uses `bar = ...` instead of `foo =...`. I've significantly curtailed my dupehammering lately because of this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes I can imagine that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Personally, I put as much effort into my reviews as the OP seems to have put into their answer. Now before you jump down my throat with a pile of downvotes, let me explain what I mean.

If the answer I am reviewing has any things like formatting, an attempt at mostly correct grammar/spelling, code blocks, an explanation of the code, and/or has been edited, then I will actually look at why this has ended up in a review queue and will generally provide a reason why the answer has been reviewed as closable.

If the answer is something along the lines of

> Can yuo show me how 2 get a URL frm a internet paeg. I am usng Firfox and JQUERY on Ubuntu.
>   I am noob plz help with teh codes.
>   Thank you in advance

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10777192)

which has none of the above, I generally don't choose a reason.

This is because, personally, I have found that if I choose a reason, the OP seems to think something along the lines of "Someone has read my atrocity and vaguely engaged with it, maybe they can <strike>help me</strike> do my job/assignment/homework for me" and I get pinged with a either a request for assistance, or a furious demand to explain why I downvoted.

I feel like if I didn't do this, I wouldn't still be reviewing posts. I'd have given up out of frustration.

However if the answer is not someone saying "Have same problem plz help" or posting an entirely different question as an answer) 95% of the time I will provide a reason, because the answerer hasn't got as big a stake in the answer being accepted as a questioner has in getting their question answered, if that makes sense. I feel like they've at least attempted to improve the community, by providing an answer.

**TL;DR**: Declining to leave a comment is an option for a reason. If you feel like the OP should understand why their answer is not acceptable if they had read the Help Center, then feel free to decline to provide a comment.

Comment: *I put as much effort into my reviews as the OP seems to have put into their question* - I respectfully disagree. If someone posts a link only answer that involved no effort whatsoever, then you should vote to delete it as **link only answer**. That way, the OP will understand that he is supposed to add some info. Voting to delete it with **no comments needed** might not help him.

Comment: Questions don't go anymore into the Low Quality Posts review queue since Triage is a thing. The only questions that you see there are audits. You should probably revise your answer.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Yes, that's why I said, I treat questions differently to answers.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Oh my bad. I've edited my answer

Comment: @ArtjomB. [this is announcement about new flow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/839601) "The VLQ flag is dead - long live VLQ!" (March 2015)

Comment: I've accepted this as answer, because I like it, but I wonder if the powers that be are ok with it, or if it's one of those things, we, as a community, are allowed to decide.

Comment: @MsYvette It's one of these things that only the community can decide. If people aren't willing to to leave comments, for whatever reason, there isn't much that anyone can do about it.

Answer (score 8):

> Do other reviewers feel this way about commenting?

I can't speak for other people here on SO, but personally I almost always ensure that I choose the most appropriate reason when I vote to delete such posts.

> Is it a problem not to use a comment?

Yes, the OP will never know what is wrong with his post and will probably end up committing the same mistake again.

> Would it be better to skip, even though I am sure of my vote, but am
>   not keen to leave a comment?

I strongly discourage this. 90 percent of the times, people won't target you for voting to close / delete their posts. A vote without proper reason will not help anyone in any way. If you get into trouble, we always have mods who will take appropriate actions to ensure your *safety* from trolls :P

PS : Choose *No comment needed* option when the post is really bad and / or has severe formatting problems.

Comment: I'm relatively new to the 2K queues, but I generally follow a similar policy of selecting the option appropriate to the reason I'd delete a LQ post. If I find none of the options match, then I choose the default (no comment). Up until now no one has "looked for a fight" over it...

Comment: @CindyMeister - Exactly. I don't see why a person should be scared of doing the right thing :)

Comment: When you say "I strongly discourage this", do you mean not leaving a comment, skipping when you don't want to comment, or both?

Comment: @Anders - I meant I strongly discourage *not leaving a comment* when you vote.

Comment: No doubt I'm with you, review is  to clean up but also to help out users. Lets not be afraid!! there is already From Review in comment but maybe a notification to user when it is flag could help to avoid user blaming review comment..

Comment: @PetterFriberg nice idea, then people will be asking the same question about flagging :D

Comment: @MsYvette, the idea was not to have in notification the user that flag it... but something like this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262949/question-downvote-flag-notification, Shog9  denied this since they will not edit an I can agree, but from this perspective helping reviewer's that are afraid of troubles it could be useful.

Comment: @PetterFriberg yes that's a very good idea. I agree with it

Comment: @MsYvette, it could a simple notification like "Your answer has been flagged as not an answer, it will therefore be passed to a review que and other users are asked to help to identify why"

Comment: @PetterFriberg yes I think under the post, so it's visible, automated, not a private inbox, that way it's publicly visible

Comment: @MsYvette, don't know I think SO don't like it like this, because it will induce other users to flag.... but I'm sure Shog9 knows best if this is useful and if so how it should be implemented...

Comment: @PetterFriberg yes it's not so simple, as then it could be abused.

Comment: @PetterFriberg - I am pretty sure that this feature request will not be accepted. I see no reason to tell the OP that his post *is probably going to be* removed :P

Comment: @MsYvette another simple solution would be to included it in the review comment, before the text, make it clear that the review user is only trying to help

Comment: However I think that it should worry SO that this answer is not the most voted and accepted one... I think they are very keen to help both reviewers and users.....

Comment: @MsYvette - Is someone troubling you?. In my 3 years on SO Ive seldom seen people abusing the reviewers. Yes. there will be one or 2 cases every now and then but the mods and other SO members ensure that SO is a sane place to be on :)

Comment: I will try to post a feature request on meta lets see what happens....

Comment: @PetterFriberg - Good luck. I hope that it gets accepted, not sure if it will be :P

Comment: @MsYvette, posted a follow up on our discussion http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314090/modify-the-the-automatic-review-comment-to-help-out-both-reviewers-and-op, feel free to edit it.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar yeh I think a few of us have had difficulty, which is why the accepted answer's been upvoted. We all know what the best thing is to do, but are tired of being called out for doing it. Also I've been replying to Petter's comment here :) I think your answer is an ideal answer, but if people them avoid reviewing to save the fall out, that's not a good thing either. ps I am active in the http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers so cop my fair share of disgruntled user feed back :D