# Extended plagiarism, how many to flag?

Tags: support, flags, plagiarism

I just tripped over a user that has a rather extensive percentage of plagiarized answers (and questions, and plagiarized answers to their own plagiarized question..).

I've flagged half a dozen of them with links to original sources, but I'm sure there are more. Will the moderators take it from here or should I continue?

Comment: I'd flag them manually where the posts are different. Compacting the questions along with the link to where it's plagiarized from in 600 chars isn't easy. If there's reposts of a post that has been plagiarized, those make sense to put in the same flag. At least that's how I handle it.

Comment: When I've gone down this rabbit hole, I've usually flagged 4-5 posts with comments like _repeated plagiarism from this user_ or _5th case of plagiarism from this user_. It's worked out well, mods have gone through their history.

Comment: Tracking down plagiarism is a lot of work, we always appreciate it if someone goes the extra mile and identify sources for each post! For this specific user, I checked the remaining answers and am fairly confident we found all cases.

Comment: See the Uber-Meta [FAQ on plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered), where step 4 is *go hunt for more*.

Comment: @Zoe Just an idea: You may use the IDs of the posts instead of full links.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed that only works for on-site links

Comment: I have sometimes had such a substantial report to make on a user (usually in relation to voting fraud across many questions) that I compile all the data into a private GitHub Gist and then add the link to the mod report. That approach has been appreciated so far (even if it is not ideal to have a mod report that can effectively be deleted by the reporter).

Comment: Plain simple solution is
**Block that user from the site**
It is fair and simple! No more second thoughts are required!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Like [Martijn Pieters linked in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384614/extended-plagiarism-how-many-to-flag#comment693880_384614), there is [official guidance for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> 4. Go hunt for more
>
> Moderators have enough to do already - they won't be able to check out
>   a user's entire profile for further instances of plagiarism. If you
>   feel like it, take that task upon yourself, and flag each occurrence
>   as described above.

The reason for this being, hunting down and documenting plagiarism is hard. Someone will have to do it eventually, so you might as well give the moderators a hand if you're willing and have the time to spare. This is different from serial voting because the moderators have exactly the same tools for finding plagiarism that users have, so you're just as effective as they are in getting to the bottom of it.

Comment: Can't in cases like this user be warned about his actions though and that further transgression will lead to account suspension? It's not like anyone is going to dedicate their time on SO monitoring suspect individuals on regular basis

Comment: @Rawrplus In addition to deleting or editing plagiarised content, moderators will issue suspensions and warnings to users. That happens in addition to flagging up cases of plagiarism.

Comment: Um... isn't it SO's goal to moderate content, not users? This answer seems to suggest, or maybe support, targeting a user. Granted, they absolutely shouldn't plagiarize, but it's the principal. It's bad idea to say something that can be taken as, "it's to target a user as long as you have a good reason". Maybe it needs rewording?

Comment: @Chipster [There is nothing wrong with searching for more instances of plagiarism from a user that has already displayed a history of it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289393/)

Comment: @Chipster moderators target users all the time. It's their job :) In some chatrooms you cannot target users as a rule, that's when you flag the user for moderation. But when we see spam or plagiarism, we generally check user other posts for more.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I guess. Maybe I'm thinking of the close-vote SO room, which says not to target users.